# OP accepts answer, then vandalizes the question

Tags: discussion, support

https://stackoverflow.com/q/40254172/18157

I provided an answer, which was accepted by the OP.  After that point the OP has vandalized the question to remove all the code, and engaged in an edit war with people who have attempted to roll back the vandalism.

I have flagged for moderator attention, but wonder if there is anything else I should (or can) do.

Comment: Rollback vandalism. What else?

Comment: I'd rather not get involved in an edit war.  I did one rollback and the OP undid it within 20 seconds.

Comment: Trying to cover up cheating on a school assignment, no doubt. Moderators can lock the post once they see it. Until then, rolling back changes is all you can do.

Comment: @BilltheLizard OK, thanks.

Comment: Probably you may raise custom flag and tell moderators about "edit war". By any means OP shouldn't vandalize his question himself, including inserted code snippet.

Comment: Put my 2 cents.

Comment: @JimGarrison You probably should stay away from answering that kinda s**t but just down- and close vote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought it was interesting... I got to research MIPS architecture (never looked at it before) and learned that it owes a lot to IBM/370 (in which I was an expert in the 70's & 80's).  The question itself wasn't _that_ bad... and I had fun answering it :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior is often seen on homework assignments.

Rolling back such self-vandalism is the first call to action. I normally leave a stock comment to notify the OP that such actions are not appreciated.

After 3 rollbacks an mod flag is raised but it doesn't hurt to raise a custom flag as well to provide the mod with context what is going on and a request to either lock the question or warn the user.

By posting the OP agreed with the terms laid out in the [legal stuff](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> #### 3. Subscriber Content
>
> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and, except as otherwise set forth herein, to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, **even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.**

*emphasis is mine*

If the OP doesn't want to be linked to their post they can use the [Contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form and request the post to be [disassociated from their account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239366/could-we-have-a-help-center-page-on-disassociating-posts)